# I am using viewpager2 inside a recyclerview but the images are not outputting. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

No matter what I do the pictures are not showing up.

Even if I set the items to match parent, I still have the same problem, I've been dealing with it since the morning, if I find it, I will relax very well :D

This is my adapter for viewpager 2 :

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter ( private val context : Context , private val album_id : Int , private val photo_list : ArrayList<Photos> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.PagerHolder>()  {
    
        inner class PagerHolder (view : View ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder ( view ) {
    
            var image_view : ImageView
    
            init {
    
                image_view = view.findViewById ( R.id.pager_imageview )
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent : ViewGroup, viewType : Int) : PagerHolder {
    
            val v = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.context ).inflate ( R.layout.viewpager_item , parent , false )
    
            return PagerHolder ( v )
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder (holder : ViewPagerAdapter.PagerHolder, position : Int ) {
    
            val list = photo_list.filter { it.albumId == album_id }
    
            for ( i in list [ position ].url ) {
    
                    Glide.with ( context ).load ( i.toString() ).diskCacheStrategy ( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL ).into ( holder.image_view )
            }
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount ( ) : Int {
    
            return photo_list.size
        }
    }
```

This is my xml code for my viewpager items :

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pager_imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is my recyclerview defined codes:

```
class AlbumRecyclerAdapter (  private val context : Context , private val album_list : ArrayList<Albums> , private val photo_list : ArrayList<Photos> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumRecyclerAdapter.Adapterholder>() {

    inner class Adapterholder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        var album_title : TextView

        var view_pager2 : ViewPager2

        init {

            album_title = view.findViewById(R.id.album_title)

            view_pager2 = view.findViewById ( R.id.view_pager2 )
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent : ViewGroup, viewType : Int) : Adapterholder {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.context ).inflate ( R.layout.album_recycler_list , parent , false )

        return Adapterholder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder ( holder : AlbumRecyclerAdapter.Adapterholder , position : Int) {

        val pager_adapter = ViewPagerAdapter ( context , album_list [ position ].id ,  photo_list )

        holder.view_pager2.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL
        holder.view_pager2.adapter = pager_adapter
        holder.view_pager2.clipToPadding = false
        holder.view_pager2.clipChildren = false
        holder.view_pager2.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        holder.view_pager2.getChildAt ( 0 ).overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

        holder.album_title.text = album_list [ position ].title
    }

    override fun getItemCount ( ) : Int {

        return album_list.size
    }
}
```

Finally , this is my xml code for the recyclerview :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft ="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Album Title"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager2" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Java Developer so I cannot code with Kotlin but I'll show you how to show images on `ViewPager`.

First, remove `for ( i in list [ position ].url )` from `onBindViewHolder`. And load direct from `photo_list.get(position).getImage` as below

```
override fun onBindViewHolder (holder : ViewPagerAdapter.PagerHolder, position : Int ) {
    
            val list = photo_list.filter { it.albumId == album_id }
    
                    Glide.with ( context ).load ( photo_list.get(position).getImage // your imageModel ).diskCacheStrategy ( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL ).into ( holder.image_view )
        }
```

Make sure to change `JAVA` to `Kotlin` in my code. If you any problem is causing, Let me know

Comment: Didn't work viewpager adapter returns empty data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the whole `photo_list` and then `filter`ing it in `ViewPager`, pass only the `filter`ed list to it. Because in `getItemCount` you are returning the size of the whole `photo_list` but in `onBindViewHolder` you're accessing the `filter`ed list, this could lead to crashes as `filter`ed list would be smaller than the original one.

In `AlbumRecyclerAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` pass the filtered list to `ViewPager` adapter.

```
val pager_adapter = ViewPagerAdapter ( 
    context , 
    album_list [ position ].id ,  
    ArrayList(photo_list.filter { it.albumId == album_list[position].id }
)
```

In `ViewPagerAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder()`, why are you iterating over a `url` and I assume your `url` is a `String` and when you iterate over it, it loops through all the individual characters of the string, that is why you are not seeing any image in the first place.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder (holder : ViewPagerAdapter.PagerHolder, position : Int ) {
    val photo = photo_list[position]
    
    Glide.with ( context )
        .load ( photo.url )
        .diskCacheStrategy ( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
        .into ( holder.image_view )
}
```

Comment: Didn't work viewpager adapter returns empty data

Comment: Where are you exactly getting empty data?

Comment: I removed the for loop and managed to get the position parameter and the url data one by one, but for some reason all the images return empty when I use only the glide part.

Comment: try debugging and check if urls have any value or not.